# `ansible --version` command throws an ERROR

Tags: pip, ansible

Good Day guys

I have installed ansible on my mac, it was successfully installed but then when I run the command `ansible --version` it throws me a n error:

```
Unhandled error:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 559, in update_config_data
    value, origin = self.get_config_value_and_origin(config, configfile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 503, in get_config_value_and_origin
    value = ensure_type(value, defs[config].get('type'), origin=origin)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 124, in ensure_type
    value = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix, dir=value)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 339, in mkdtemp
    _os.mkdir(file, 0700)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/patrick/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37505vvsQNX'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible", line 62, in <module>
    import ansible.constants as C
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/constants.py", line 174, in <module>
    config = ConfigManager()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 291, in __init__
    self.update_config_data()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 571, in update_config_data
    raise AnsibleError("Invalid settings supplied for %s: %s\n" % (config, to_native(e)), orig_exc=e)
ansible.errors.AnsibleError: Invalid settings supplied for DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/patrick/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37505vvsQNX'
```

Appreciate your help guys.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I did install it via pip 'sudo pip install ansible'

Answer (score 4):

Check if this is similar to [iiab/iiab/issue 1212](https://github.com/iiab/iiab/issues/1212):

> After some more digging, I found the real source of this problem was hardcoded paths in ansible.cfg

Or the more recent [`ansible/galaxy-dev` issue 107](https://github.com/ansible/galaxy-dev/issues/107), which leads to [PR 110](https://github.com/ansible/galaxy-dev/pull/110):

> The default ansible temp dir `~/.ansible/tmp` is accessed by `ansible-doc` via the `galaxy-importer`.
>   This works OK in the `galaxy-dev` local env, but on the CI environment it attempts to create dir `/.ansible/tmp` and fails.
>
> This PR changes the default ansible temp dir to `/tmp/ansible` which is outside the user home (and in the local env, `/tmp` has greater permissions)

Try and change [`DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-local-tmp) to `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting error

```
ERROR: Unhandled exception when retrieving DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-738828nkwy1p1'. [Errno 13] Permission denied: '~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-738828nkwy1p1'
ERROR: ... requires at least Ansible 4+/core 2.11 installed. Please run ./setup to upgrade Ansible
```

My folder `~/.ansible/tmp` exists, but it lacked permissions. After doing

`sudo chmod 777 ~/.ansible/tmp`

Now `ansible --version` works!

Answer (score 0):

~/.ansible/tmp is probably root, so not accessible. chown it to user

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled 'gathering' in ansible.cfg to fix the issue.

```
# gathering = False
```

Below error occurring before commenting this.

```
~ % ansible
Unhandled error:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 627, in update_config_data
    value, origin = self.get_config_value_and_origin(config, configfile)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 586, in get_config_value_and_origin
    raise AnsibleOptionsError('Invalid value "%s" for configuration option "%s", valid values are: %s' %
ansible.errors.AnsibleOptionsError: Invalid value "False" for configuration option "setting: DEFAULT_GATHERING ", valid values are: implicit, explicit, smart
```

Answer (score 0):

In the control plane, check the permissions of the ".ansible" folder. In this case, it seems to be in the folder /Users/patrick folder. Make sure the user who is executing ansible has proper permissions to that .ansible folder. If not, set the correct permissions using chown command.